# Generate hour gaps from ranges

Tags: oracle

I have following data, which has within the same date some hour gaps. I would like to populate the missing hours, but to set additionally an upper and lower bound (e.g. from 08:00 to 17:00):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6WTX.png)

Comment: ok, let us forget about the bounds for the moment, I can cut them out later on. What about missing hours with MATCH_RECOGNIZE?

Comment: Why are you fixated on using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`? You don't need to use that.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` contains both date and time components so you can store both in the same column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (from_dt DATE, to_dt DATE);

INSERT INTO table_name (from_dt, to_dt)
SELECT DATE '2023-09-25' + INTERVAL '08:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       DATE '2023-09-25' + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-09-25' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       DATE '2023-09-25' + INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Then to generate the missing data, you can use the `LEAD` analytic function for the trailing intervals and `UNION ALL` if the start interval is missing:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (from_dt, to_dt)
SELECT from_dt, to_dt
FROM   (
  SELECT to_dt AS from_dt,
         LEAD(from_dt, 1, TRUNC(to_dt) + INTERVAL '17:00' HOUR TO MINUTE) OVER (
           PARTITION BY TRUNC(from_dt)
           ORDER BY from_dt
         ) AS to_dt
  FROM   table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC(from_dt) + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         MIN(from_dt)
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY TRUNC(from_dt)
)
WHERE from_dt < to_dt;
```

Then, after the `INSERT`, the table will contain:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY from_dt;
```

| FROM_DT | TO_DT |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-25 08:00:00 | 2023-09-25 08:30:00 |
| 2023-09-25 08:30:00 | 2023-09-25 09:00:00 |
| 2023-09-25 09:00:00 | 2023-09-25 10:00:00 |
| 2023-09-25 10:00:00 | 2023-09-25 12:00:00 |
| 2023-09-25 12:00:00 | 2023-09-25 17:00:00 |

---

If you really want to have separate date and time columns then:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name2 (
  dt        DATE CHECK(dt = TRUNC(dt)),
  from_time INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0),
  to_time   INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)
);

INSERT INTO table_name2 (dt, from_time, to_time)
SELECT DATE '2023-09-25',
       INTERVAL '08:30' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-09-25',
       INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
       INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
FROM   DUAL
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name2 (dt, from_time, to_time)
SELECT dt, from_time, to_time
FROM   (
  SELECT dt,
         to_time AS from_time,
         LEAD(from_time, 1, INTERVAL '17:00' HOUR TO MINUTE) OVER (
           PARTITION BY dt
           ORDER BY from_time
         ) AS to_time
  FROM   table_name2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dt,
         INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         MIN(from_time)
  FROM   table_name2
  GROUP BY dt
)
WHERE from_time < to_time;
```

And then the table contains:

| DT | FROM_TIME | TO_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | +0 08:00:00 | +0 08:30:00 |
| 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | +0 08:30:00 | +0 09:00:00 |
| 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | +0 09:00:00 | +0 10:00:00 |
| 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | +0 10:00:00 | +0 12:00:00 |
| 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | +0 12:00:00 | +0 17:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_3Naax_N)

Comment: strange, but when I use the insert & select for lower option( separated date and time columns) I get different result: only 3 rows: 08:00-08:30/09:00-10:00/12:00-17:00. And if I modify it: insert first row from e.g. 08:00 till 08:30 then I get following results: 08:00-08:00/08:30-10:00/12:00-17:00. Is the select query generalized for any kind of gaps? Seems that it is taylored for my example from the top.

Comment: @kirilb It should be generalised for any gaps (on the assumption that the times will be between 08:00 and 17:00 and there will be no overlapping ranges). I cannot replicate your result [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NMxR5BBE) as it only inserts 2 rows and does not generate a 08:00 - 08:00 range (the only reason why I can see that it would behave like that is if the final `WHERE` clause was accidentally omitted).